# What is the max practical limit for WebRtc peer connections?

Tags: webrtc

As in how many connections can you have via webrtc before performance is affected? Will this technology advance to higher and higher possible connections? Thanks

Comment: As with any performance issue, the easiest solution is to just measure it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No performance issues yet - trying to decide if webrtc is right tech for web app and want to know theoretical limits, not limits that may be limited by code or my lack of experience.

Comment: In the end, it all depends where you draw the arbitrary lines. Any number of connections will affect performance, the question is how much is acceptable. Same for the other half, pretty much any technology can be expected to be somewhat faster/better/etc in the future, the question is how much does it matter.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but im just hoping for some numbers to work with so i can make a decision. I want a general idea if 100s/1000s of connections is possible or will be any time soon, or if there is a way to redirect the connection to servers if the load increases over a certain point. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Anecdotally, I know Appear.in's maximum practical limit was 8 (last time I checked) for video conferencing in which each peer was connected to every other peer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if it was one peer connected to many?